# compare two tables with same column for similar values

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `tableA` and `tableB`. Both have two similar columns `ID` and `B_ID`.
I want to check whether both table have similar values. My code is:

```
$ac = $mysql->query("(SELECT ID,B_ID FROM tableA) INTERSECT (SELECT ID,B_ID FROM tableB)");

  if($ac){
    while($row  = $ac->fetch_assoc()){

      echo "ID ".$row["ID"]." B_ID".$row["B_ID"]."<br>";
    }
  }
```

But this doesn't give any result.

```
    ps: tableA(ID,B_ID)

 1->23
 2->23
 3->23
 4->56
 5->67

tableB(ID,B_ID)

3->23
8->26
11->27
12->66
```

here both table has 3->23 but 1->23 2->23 is not in tableB how can i figure that sort of records. same B_ID but different ID

Comment: try to use simple join query

Comment: Do you mean value of `B_ID` only or both columns `ID and B_ID` must be similar ?

Comment: similar B_ID but different ID. i mean both tables can have both similar values. i want to get the different values

Answer (score 1):

If you have B.ID column is present in both table then use following JOIN query

```
SELECT a.ID, a.B_ID 
FROM tableA AS a
JOIN tableB AS b ON (a.B_ID = b.B_ID AND a.ID = b.ID)
```

Comment: how to find  a.ID != b.ID records

Comment: you can simply change the ON condition to (a.B_ID = b.B_ID AND a.ID != b.ID)

Comment: but it gives a.ID = b.ID results also

Comment: then try that condition in where clause ON (a.B_ID = b.B_ID) WHERE a.ID != b.ID

Answer (score 0):

Use a join to get the data and just iterate over your results. Run the query and if there is any record that satisfies the query or not.

```
select t1.ID, t1.B_ID from tableA t1, tableB t2
where t1.ID = t2.ID
and   t1.B_ID =t2.B_ID
```

Comment: how can i find (t1.B_ID =t2.B_ID ) and (t1.ID != t2.ID) results

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INNER JOIN` and `COUNT`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.B_ID = tableB.B_ID AND tableA.ID = tableB.ID
```

now if cnt is greater than zero than common values exist, otherwise no

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this query may be help full.

```
SELECT
    tbla.ID,
    tbla.B_ID
FROM
    tablea AS tbla,
    tableb AS tblb
WHERE
    tbla.B_ID = tblb.B_ID
```

Comment: how to find a.ID != b.ID records

Comment: @user3358839 Do you mean want records with not equal ID ? if yes then add below statement.

`AND tbla.ID != tblb.ID`